Are there networking charges for traffic between "Firebase Realtime Database" and "Cloud Run Services" in the same region?
According to the Firebase pricing page, the Realtime Database has a free cost until 10GB of data transferred. After I've joined the "Blaze plan", I could see at https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/MY-PROJECT-NAME/usage another information, that says I've a no-cost quota of 360MB/day, which means I'd have to pay if this threshold is exceeded, even if the free cost until 10GB of data transferred hasn't reached. Here an answer about 360MB/day cost.
According to the Authenticating service-to-service page,

There are no networking charges for service-to-service traffic between
two services in the same region.

According to the Realtime Database billing support page:

Firebase Realtime Database bills based on the data you store and for
all outbound traffic, including "access denied" responses. This
includes SSL encryption overhead for each separate connection.

According to the Understand Realtime Database Billing page:

Firebase bills for the data you store in your database and all
outbound network traffic at the session layer (layer 5) of the OSI
model.

After gathering all that information, I could say that for the scenario below I wouldn't be charged, as for the "Authenticating" part I shouldn't be charged, as well for the "network traffic at the session layer", because in the scenario bellow the traffic is supposed to be "inbound".
But, I'll still with the question, as it was a bit difficult to put together all the information and, I'm not 100% sure yet.
Scenario / Question:
So, if I have a scenario where I have Cloud Run Services making operations (reading/writing) directly on the Realtime Database, and they are all in the same region, will this "reading/writing" be charged?
